# Upload zipped files to SharePoint Document Library Office 365 using SSIS (vb.net / C#.net)

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint, ssis, office365

I need to upload a zipped file from local folder to SharePoint document library. I'm unable to use WebClient PUT method for this upload to Office 365 SharePoint site. Please share the code using C# or VB.net, as I need to implement this in SSIS package.

Comment: "*Please share code*" ? What have you tried? This isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options available, depending on your access to the SharePoint server.  Take a look at the following:

[Uploading Files Into SharePoint Using a SSIS Custom Task](http://www.newsignature.co.uk/uploading-files-into-sharepoint-using-a-ssis-custom-task/)

[How to Upload an Excel File to SharePoint Portal from SSIS](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b72e5ed-baae-48e1-a832-4eddad7d82e2/how-to-upload-an-excel-file-to-sharepoint-portal-from-ssis?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

The file type is not so important, but you may need to also incorporate a check-in/check-out process with SharePoint.  You'll need to gather additional details for this process and it would be a good idea to also follow up with the SharePoint administrator for more information.

Answer (score 0):

We Can able to upload using Script Task. 
First we need to install (share point client) in the system where we are running the SSIS package.

See the below script task C# code on VS2015

```
#region Namespaces
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Data;
#endregion

namespace ST_14e7d12d30c54d54a1eaa0bfa5961c5b
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {



        public static class Utils
        {

            public static SharePointOnlineCredentials GetO365Credentials(string userName, string passWord)
            {
                SecureString securePassWord = new SecureString();

                foreach (char c in passWord.ToCharArray()) securePassWord.AppendChar(c);

                SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassWord);

                return credentials;

            }
        }

        public void Main()
        {

            try
            {

                //Set the Sharepoint URL (Till the folder that the files needs to be uploaded)
                string siteUrl = "https://AAAAAAAAA.sharepoint.com/BBBBBBBB/CCCCCCCC";


               //FQDN source file details passing from the package 
                string filePath = @Dts.Variables["User::SharePoint_SrcFile"].Value.ToString();

                //Destination File Path (inclueds file name and full share point adddress)
                string DestinationfilePath = @Dts.Variables["User::Sharepoint_DestLocation"].Value.ToString();

                //loging the processing file
                bool fireAgain = true;
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0,"","Source File Processing:" + filePath + " || Share Point Dest:" + DestinationfilePath,"", 0,ref fireAgain);

                //Setting the library name (can find from the share point site)
                string libraryName = "Documents";

                ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

                ctx.RequestTimeout = 1000000;

                //Retriveng user name and password from project parameeter (Password set as sensitive)
                string sharepointusername = @Dts.Variables["$Project::sSharePointUserName"].Value.ToString();
                string sharepointPassword = @Dts.Variables["$Project::sSharePointPassword"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString();


                //Authenticating (using the sharepoint client installed)
                ctx.Credentials = Utils.GetO365Credentials(sharepointusername, sharepointPassword);

                Web web = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(web, a => a.ServerRelativeUrl);

                List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);

                ctx.ExecuteQuery();


                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))

                {

                    FileCreationInformation flciNewFile = new FileCreationInformation();

                    flciNewFile.ContentStream = fs;

                    flciNewFile.Url = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                    flciNewFile.Overwrite = true;

                    //Upload URL

                    flciNewFile.Url = DestinationfilePath.ToString() ;


                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile);

                    //ctx.Load(uploadFile);
                    uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["Title"] = "sharepoint";
                    uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();

                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            }




        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(0,"", ex.Message, "", 0);
            }


        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion
```